# How do you refresh a database view when using Domino Java API?

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I'm using the Domino Java API to query a database on a remote server. The server is processing the documents, and I'm trying to get their status. However, when I create the session, and run a query, even if I loop and check again every 30 seconds, my code will never see those documents update- it only sees the status at the time it created the first query. I have a few more loops, but the basic code outline is below- can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Is there a way to update the current Database view from the Java API? The databases are not full text indexed, and cannot be due to outside constraints.

```
public static boolean queryDatabase(String adminFilePath, String targetItem)
    NotesThread.sinitThread();
    Session session =NotesFactory.createSession((String) null, (String) null, (String) null);
    Registration Reg = s.createRegistration();
    Reg.switchToID(adminFilePath, password);
    DocumentCollection dc = getRecentDocsFromDB(session);
    numResults=dc.getCount();
    if (numResults > 0) {
        //loop through documents to find what I'm looking for
        //if the documents contain "done", finish, else:
        Thread.sleep(60000);
        session.recycle();
        session=SessionFactory.newSession(adminFilePath, "password");
        dc = getRecentDocsFromDB(session);
        found = searchDocumentCollection(dc, targetItem); 
        //this is essentially doing the same thing again- create a session, get docs made in the
        //past day or so, and loop through looking for the ones I need. 
}

private static DocumentCollection getRecentDocsFromDB(Session session){
    Database db = SessionFactory.openDatabase(session, server, database);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    DateTime dt = session.createDateTime(cal);
    DocumentCollection dc = searchNotesDBUsingDate(session, db,"Form=\"event\"", dt);
}

public static DocumentCollection searchNotesDBUsingDate(Session session,
        Database database, String query, DateTime dt) throws NotesException {
    DocumentCollection dc = null;
    dc = database.search(query, dt);
    return dc;
}
```

I've updated the code with a session.recycle() call. (Thanks for the suggestion!) In testing, it's not having any effect- the code is working for the first document, but then never sees a second document being called.
It's insane, because it seems to be caching the session anyway!

Comment: Am I being stupid, or do you never update `numResults` in your loop?

Comment: Thats my fault- didn't copy and paste that part of the code, just left a comment to say there's a loop. Inside that if statement is a while loop which re-runs everything. The numResults, if it's zero, says that there aren't any documents created in the last 24 hours- which is an error scenario for me anyway.

Comment: I'm wondering, are you really creating a new session? I.e. are you closing the old session properly, or is the framework providing you with the same session because there already is a valid one?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing- there's no session.destroy or session.close method, so is there a valid way to do this? I mean, as a hack, I could set session=null. But I'm still unsure if Domino would properly destroy it.

Comment: Well there is `recycle`, but I'm really grasping at straws here - my experience is with Hibernate and Spring.

Comment: So far I don't see any code that reads a Notes view.  Please update your question to include the implementation of searchNotesDBUsingDate.  The implementation of that method could help folks come up with an answer.

Comment: Added the method, which literally uses the database search method. The date is used to restrict the search- it only finds documents since that date.

Comment: Well, Database.Search isn't reading a view. It's doing a search. That's different. It's a brute force way of doing things. But that's beside the point. Stupid question: are you sure your variable server is set correctly? If it's an empty string, you would be opening a local replica of the database rather than the  database that's on the server where the docs are being processed.

Comment: It's definitely setting the server variable, as it's working for some servers. Basically, if the server is fast, then the code catches the documents in the correct state. If the server is slower, then it grabs the first document correctly, but never grabs subsequent ones in an updated state. And yes, it's a very brute force way of doing the search, but I wasn't able to find a way of searching views?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the problem, but I wasn't able to.  In my tests, `Database.search()` always returns the latest documents -- even if a document is added after the database is opened.  I suspect there is a subtle problem in your code (perhaps what Richard Schwartz suggested in his comment).

It may or may not be relevant, but I wasn't able to compile your version of `getRecentDocsFromDB()` because I don't have a `SessionFactory` class.  My version just uses `Session.getDatabase()` like so:

```
private static DocumentCollection getRecentDocsFromDB(Session session, String server, String database) throws NotesException {
    Database db = session.getDatabase(server, database);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    DateTime dt = session.createDateTime(cal);
    DocumentCollection dc = searchNotesDBUsingDate(session, db,"Form=\"event\"", dt);
    return dc;
}
```

Also, as Richard mentioned, you are not reading a view.  You are searching the database for all documents created (or modified) by the "event" form in the last 24 hours.  And you are doing this in a tight loop.  Even if you get it to work, this approach isn't the best for production.  You might want to research the use of `lotus.domino.View` and `lotus.domino.ViewNavigator`.